# How do I use a different connection string with my DbContext class & for migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

We have different DB users (with differing permissions) that we use for read/write operations (`readwrite`) and for creating/modifying tables (`modifytable`).

I want to use a connection string with `readwrite` user for the `DbContext` class and was able to do it this way in the `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ReadWriteContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(rwConnString));
```

How do I do the equivalent for the migrations part (i.e., giving it a connection string with the user `modifytable`)?

All the examples I've seen simply talk about running the following command in NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

and then

```
Update-Database
```

How (& from where) does this `Update-Database` pick up the connection string? How do I supply a custom connection string?

We construct the connection string using some logic that takes some values from Azure Key Vault, so reading it from a configuration file is not an option.

I'm brand new to EF.

Comment: You can specify the connection string in the command line with the `--connection` parameter. In .NET Core migrations are performed on any OS using [dotnet ef migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update) not the VS-only Powershell commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution to my problem: the `Update-Database` command takes a connection string:

```
Update-Database -connection <connection_string>
```